# Randomly selecting integers with prescribed minimal distance and estimations

Tags: references, algorithms, random-generation, asymptotics, combinatorics

I am interested in sequences of  $M$ distinct integers in $[[1,N]]$ (integers from $1$ to $N$) such that  integers $I_m$ are separated by at least $\delta$ integers (taking into account the outer bounds $0$ and $N+1$)?  For instance with $N=11$, $M=3$ and $\delta=2$, we impose that $|I_m-I_{n}|\ge 3$ when $m\neq n$; only the sequence $(3,6,9)$ is valid. For $\delta=1$, there are more admissible sequences ($(2,4,6),(2,4,7),(2,4,8),(2,4,9),(2,4,10),(2,5,7),(2,5,8),\dots$). I imagine that this problem has been tackled. Yet I lack appropriate references, keywords and algorithms. I suspect this could be related to a concept of discrepancy.

The lazy approach I have used so far is to divide $N+1$ into $M+1$ intervals (when $\delta(M+1)+M\le N$) and pick the  $I_m$ inside those intervals. This is however totally suboptimal in the diversity of sequences.

1. How to randomly pick (when this is possible) uniformly an admissible sequence?
2. Can one compute the number of admissible sequences (with $N$, $M$ and $\delta$)?
3. Or can one estimate asymptotics  in a regime where $M$ is sensibly smaller than $N$ (say $M \sim N^\lambda$, $\lambda \le \frac{1}{2}$)?

In practice, I would use such an algorithm on sequences with typically $N \in[10^3,\dots,10^6]$ and $\delta \in[[1,10]]$.

Comment: There are several ways to _define_ this distribution: one is to list all admissible sequences and pick one of them uniformly at random. Another is to go sequential: pick a number at random in $\{1+\delta,\ldots,N-\delta\}$, then another number at random among the admissible one, until the last one or until an impossibility occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This answer only addresses point (2), the combinatorics.

> Can one compute the number of admissible sequences (with N, M and δ)?

### Special case of $\delta=1$

In the special case of $\delta = 1$, your problem is equivalent to the [$k$-composition of $N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) with $k = M+1$. If you think of the set of steps $a_i$ between elements of your sequence, you need the composition of $N+1$ into $k$ parts:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i = N+1$$

It's $N+1$, because as I understand from your first example, you want to enforce that the last number in the sequence must be more than $\delta$ away from $N+1$

The binomial coefficient ${N\choose k-1}$ gives the number of such compositions.
Of course, the elements of the sequence that you care about would be $x_j = \sum_{i=0}^j a_i$.

### General case

For arbitrary $\delta$, this becomes the $S$-restricted composition - $S$ is the set of integers that can be chosen to form the sum.  In your case $\{ s : s > \delta\}$ There is an expression for it in ["Restricted Weighted Integer Compositionsand Extended Binomial Coefficients"](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf) (See Equation (3))

To summarize, form this polynomial of $x$:
$$ \sum_{s\in S}( x^s )^k$$
the coefficient of degree $x^{N+1}$ gives the number of $S$-restricted compositions of $N+1$.

#### Example

Your example of:
$N=11$, $M=3$, $\delta=2$, means $k=M+1=4$, and we know there is just one way to do this.
We need to form polynomial
$$ (x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + ...)^4 $$

and find the coefficient in front of $x^{N+1} = x^{12}$. It's easy to see in this example that the coefficient is $1$, as expected.

Comment: $k$-restricted compositions and $S$-restricted ones provide a good source